# How can I make this conditional for an 'almost' random walk?

Tags: python, random

I'm new on python. I'm following some challenges and one of them is to make a "random walk" in a type of lattice, like a matrix. I was actually trying at first to define the matrix and try to make a path by some condition with the nearest neighbors but I don't know how to do that.

So I tried this other approach. I have the steps in a loop, but I can't repeat the sites that were already used. I have a random condition to choose going on horizontal or vertical, and other to avoid sites outside the "matrix" range. I've made this other condition to avoid repeated sites, using a "while" since I need to redo the random value (i or j) if it is a repeated site. I've used a "for" to analyze every time the x and y arrays for repeated values simultaneously.

```
... #before here there were some start points definitions, etc

for k in range(steps):

    if rd.randint(1,2) == 1:
        i = rd.randint(max(i-1,0),min(i+1,n))
        while ((for w in x, x[w] = i) and (for w in y, y[w] = j):
        #this "while" above isn't good, but it was to see if the w term 
        #of the x and y array were already a pair used in some previous 
        #iteration
            i = rd.randint(max(i-1,0),min(i+1,n))
    else:    
        j = rd.randint(max(j-1,0),min(j+1,n))
        while ((for w in x, x[w] = i) and (for w in y, y[w] = j):
            j = rd.randint(max(j-1,0),min(j+1,n))


    x.append(i)
    y.append(j)
```

Obviously it's not working, but I can't figure out the proper way to write, I'm just getting "invalid syntax" in all the tries that I've made. I think it would e simple by using some kind of matrix element random selection but I'm not sure how to do that too.

Thanks, I hope it is well explained.

Comment: What's this supposed to do `while ((for w in x, x[w] = i) and (for w in y, y[w] = j):`? Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial.

Comment: Before you update your post, please make sure that you read the tour part including "make it easy for others to help you".  Single-letter variables, undocumented code, and no tracing attempts make this unlikely to get much attention.

Comment: @CristiFati This should see if the pair i,j is was already used in some previous iteration. Since I need the pair I'm was trying to get a w value on the array for both x and y. But seeing now, it's worst than a previeous try. I'll make comment in the code above explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
if i not in x:
```

to check if it's in your list. No need for a for loop. Here is a way you could do it :

```
i = rd.randint(0,n)
j = rd.randint(0,n)

print("The start point is S[{},{}]".format(i,j))
x = []
y=[]
x.append(i)
y.append(j)

for k in range(10):

    if rd.randint(1,2) == 1:
        new_i = rd.randint(max(i-1,0),min(i+1,n))
        if new_i not in x:
            i = new_i
        else :
            print("I'm not moving")
    else:    
        new_j = rd.randint(max(j-1,0),min(j+1,n))
        if new_j not in y:
            j = new_j
        else :
            print("I'm not moving")


    x.append(i)
    y.append(j)
    print("My current position is x = {}; y = {}".format(i,j))
```